# How can I create a base64url from a sha256 encoded string in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, poco

This C# code:

```
            string code_verifier = "xe-V-ykFyCazK3jCWwqRCZHKAKJ0MqdZs8F6xenxjFE";
            byte[] sha256verifier = sha256(code_verifier);
            string code_challenge = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256verifier);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < sha256verifier.Length; i++)
                builder.Append(sha256verifier[i].ToString("x2"));
            output("code_verifier: " + code_verifier);
            output("builder: " + builder.ToString());
            output("code_challenge: " + code_challenge);
```

Produces these results:

```
    code_verifier: xe-V-ykFyCazK3jCWwqRCZHKAKJ0MqdZs8F6xenxjFE
    builder: 8b6526951bf46153a9a276be579ee1070f86e0812fbde8b8c37a3e64c3368525
    code_challenge: i2UmlRv0YVOpona-V57hBw-G4IEvvei4w3o-ZMM2hSU
```

I'm trying to do the same in C++ using poco, here's my code:

```
    std::string verifier_ = "xe-V-ykFyCazK3jCWwqRCZHKAKJ0MqdZs8F6xenxjFE";
    std::string sha256verifier = sha256(verifier_);
    std::stringstream ss;
    Poco::Base64Encoder b64enc(ss, Poco::BASE64_URL_ENCODING || Poco::BASE64_NO_PADDING);
    b64enc << sha256(sha256verifier);
    std::string challenge = ss.str();
    cout << "verifier: " << verifier_ << endl;
    cout << "sha256verifier: " << sha256verifier << endl;
    cout << "challenge: " << challenge << endl;
```

The result is:

```
verifier: xe-V-ykFyCazK3jCWwqRCZHKAKJ0MqdZs8F6xenxjFE
sha256verifier: 8b6526951bf46153a9a276be579ee1070f86e0812fbde8b8c37a3e64c3368525
challenge: YTIzY2U1YTYxY2IwMTU0ZmFhZjU1ZWY2ZDEyNGYzZjE3MjQzN2M1MTExNmRiZTY1ZDU1ZTc1NWY2ZjMyNjZi
```

The C# sha256() function returns a 32 element byte array which base64urlencodeNoPadding converts into a 32 character string.

The C++ sha256() function returns a 32 element hex encoded string of the same data which Poco::Base64Encoder turns into a 64 element string which bears no relation to the C# string.

How can I get the same results from C++ as I get from C# ?

This is my poco sha256 function

```
std::string::sha256(std::string buffer) {
    Poco::Crypto::RSAKey key(Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::KL_2048,
    Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::EXP_LARGE);
    Poco::Crypto::RSADigestEngine eng(key, "SHA256");
    eng.update(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
    const auto& sig = eng.digest(); // We just want the digest, unsigned.
    return Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex(sig);
}
```

Comment: I've used two sha256 functions with identical results, http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function and Poco::Crypto::RSADigestEngine

Comment: As you can see the function does `return Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex` at the end, thus returning a HEX string to you.

Comment: So can I get a char array out of it, and if so how can I generate a Base64URL encoded string from that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your C++ solution:

- you do SHA-256 twice - at `sha256(verifier_)` and `sha256(sha256verifier)`
- `Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex` converts the SHA-256 sum into a Hex string

Try something like this instead (untested):

```
std::string verifier_ = "xe-V-ykFyCazK3jCWwqRCZHKAKJ0MqdZs8F6xenxjFE";
auto sha256verifier = sha256(verifier_);
std::string challenge = toBase64(sha256verifier);
cout << "verifier: " << verifier_ << endl;
cout << "sha256verifier: " << toHex(sha256verifier) << endl;
cout << "challenge: " << challenge << endl;

std::vector<unsigned char> sha256(std::string const& buffer) {
    Poco::Crypto::RSAKey key(Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::KL_2048, Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::EXP_LARGE);
    Poco::Crypto::RSADigestEngine eng(key, "SHA256");
    eng.update(buffer.c_str(), buffer.size());
    return eng.digest();
}

std::string toBase64(std::vector<unsigned char> const& sig) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    Poco::Base64Encoder b64enc(ss, Poco::BASE64_URL_ENCODING || Poco::BASE64_NO_PADDING);
    b64enc.write((const char*)sig.data(), sig.size());
    b64enc.close();
    return ss.str();
}

std::string toHex(std::vector<unsigned char> const& sig) {
    return Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex(sig);
}
```

Comment: BTW, the double encryption was an error when simplifying out my code for the post

Comment: I spoke too soon, I just had a quick try last night and didn't notice that the encode string was too short. The sha256 result is the same as the C# but the base64 encode is three character shorter. The returned value is i2UmlRv0YVOpona-V57hBw-G4IEvvei4w3o-ZMM2 and it needs to be i2UmlRv0YVOpona-V57hBw-G4IEvvei4w3o-ZMM2hSU for google to accept it as valid. Any ideas?

Comment: According to Poco [Base64Encoder](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Base64Encoder.html) documentation, it seems you're supposed to close it. So try adding `b64enc.close();` before `return ss.str();`

Comment: I added close and now I get i2UmlRv0YVOpona-V57hBw-G4IEvvei4w3o-ZMM2hSU= which is correct apart from the single padding "=" even though no padding was specified. Anyway, I can check for and remove any padding. Thanks.